# How to kill server via terminal in VS Code?

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

Our local Macs are set up to run our local server via `grep serve`

When running from standard terminal, that command builds the project then spins up the local server. To kill it, I can use the break command  (`command-.`).

We're doing a lot more in VS Code now which has the great feature of Terminal built in. However, it appears the `command-.` doesn't apply to that version of the terminal. So I'm at a bit of a loss...how does one stop the server via the terminal in VS Code?

Comment: It should be the same in VSCode and any other terminal, crtl+c

Answer (score 1):

Crtl+c should kill the currently running process in your terminal (VSCode or otherwise).